# Vue.js pass props to dynamicly change component class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to learn Vue and encountered this problem.

```js
Vue.component('alert', {
  props: ['type', 'bold', 'msg'], template: '<div class="alert alert-{{ type }}" role="alert"><b>{{ bold }}</b> {{ msg }}</div>'
});

var componentProps=new Vue( {
    el: '#app',
  }

);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app" class="container">
  <alert type="info" bold="Greetings." msg="This is some information."></alert>
  <alert type="warning" bold="Slow down." msg="You might crash."></alert>
  <alert type="danger" bold="Oh no!" msg="The program just crashed!"></alert>
  <alert type="success" bold="Rock Out" msg="with your Props out!"></alert>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

This is in the output in the inspector.As you can see the props[type] is not changed there.

```
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-{{ type }}'"><b>Slow down.</b> You might crash.</div>
```

Link to codepen => https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/XEKbyq?editors=1010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vue 2 you [**can't** use interpolations in attributes anymore](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed). You have [several possible syntaxes for class and style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) now. In your specific case you can use:

```html
<div class="alert" :class="'alert-' + type" role="alert">
```

Demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    type: 'warning'
  }
})
```

```css
.alert { background: yellow; }
.alert-warning { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="alert" :class="'alert-' + type" role="alert"> Warning! </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

On attributes interpolation doesn't work, you can use `:` to bind

`:class="type"`

or

`:class="[ type, other, ... ]"`

or

`:class="{ 'someClass': true, 'other-class': false, 'another': method() }"`

And you can have both `:class="..."` attributes and `class="normal class attribute"` on the same element/tag